# SonarQube - duplicated block, how to change configuration

Tags: java, sonarqube

SonarQube shows me this kind of duplication:

```
1   package pl.com.bernas.ioz.user.domain;
2   
3   import java.io.Serializable;
```

This is not desired behaviour.

Can I disable this kind of duplication?
But I don't want to disable duplication rule at all, or add class to ignore. Can I ignore just this particular case?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't exclude only this type of duplication from your analyse. You can only exclude the whole file from your analyse, but this is not a good idea. Maybe you can try out the [SourceMeter plugin for SonarQube](https://www.sourcemeter.com/). It has a bit more sophisticated duplication finder. You can find an online demo [here](https://sonarqube.sourcemeter.com/).